# unable to use imported modules in event_handler lua

Tags: module, lua, event-handling

I'm writting a basic event handler in lua which uses some code located in another module

```
require "caves"

script.on_event({defines.events.on_player_dropped_item}, function(e)
    caves.init_layer(game)
    player = game.players[e.player_index]
    caves.move_down(player)
end
)
```

but whenever the event is triggered i get following error

```
attempt to index global 'caves' (a nil value)
```

why is this and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open up the module in question and see what it exports (which global variables are assigned and which locals are returned in the bottom of the file). Or pester the mod author to create interface.

Lua `require(filename)` only looks up a file `filename.lua` and runs it, which stands for module initialization. If anything is returned by running the file, it is assigned into lua's (not-so) hidden table (might as well say, a cache of the `require` function), if nothing is returned but there was no errors, the boolean `true` is assigned to that table to indicate that `filename.lua` has already been loaded before. The same `true` is returned to the variable to the left of equals in the `caves = require('caves')`.

Anything else is left up to author's conscience.
If inside the module file functions are written like this (two variants shown):

```
init_layer = function(game) 
    %do smth 
end
function move_down(player) 
    %do smth 
end
```

then after call to `require` these functions are in your global environment, overwriting your variables with same names.

If they are like this:

```
local init_layer = function(game) 
    %do smth 
end
local function move_down(player) 
    %do smth 
end
```

then you won't get them from outside.

Your code expects that the module is written as:

```
caves = {
    init_layer = function(game) 
        %do smth 
    end
}
caves.move_down=function(player) 
    %do smth 
end
```

This is the old way of doing modules, it is currently moved away, but not forbidden. Many massive libraries like `torch` still use it because you'd end up assigning them to the same named globals anyway.

Кирилл's answer is relevant to newer style:

```
local caves={
%same as above
}
%same as above
return caves
```

We here cannot know more about this. The rest is up to you, lua scripts are de-facto open-source anyways.

Addendum: The event_handler is not part of lua language, it is something provided by your host program in which lua is embedded and the corresponding tag is redundant.

You should consult your software documentation on what `script.on_event` does in this particular case it is likely does not matter, but in general the function that takes another function as argument can dump it to string and then try to load it and run in the different environment without the upvalues and globals that the latter may reference.

Answer (score 0):

`require()` does not create global table automatically, it returns module value to where you call this function. To access module via global variable, you should assign it manually:

```
local caves = require "caves"
```

Comment: when i `local caves = ...` i get the error `attempt to index upvalue 'caves' (a boolean value)`